# Symfony with buggy routing on apache

Tags: symfony

I installed Symfony on a fresh Debian 9 server.

I created a project:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton symfony
```

(masch3 is the name of my development machine)

When opening *http://masch3/symfony/public/*

I get the well known Symfony welcome page.

When I create the most simple Controller named "home"

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/home', name: 'home')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

http://masch3/symfony/public/home -> 404 not found

http://masch3/symfony/public/index.php/home -> OK

As recommended in other answers, I installed Apache pack with

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

But this still does not do.

```
php bin/console debug:router

 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler_open_file        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
  _preview_error             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  home                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /home
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------

php bin/console about

-------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Symfony
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Version              6.0.2
  Long-Term Support    No
  End of maintenance   07/2022 (in +194 days)
  End of life          07/2022 (in +194 days)
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Kernel
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Type                 App\Kernel
  Environment          dev
  Debug                true
  Charset              UTF-8
  Cache directory      ./var/cache/dev (6.8 MiB)
  Build directory      ./var/cache/dev (6.8 MiB)
  Log directory        ./var/log (19 KiB)
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  PHP
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
  Version              8.0.14
  Architecture         64 bits
  Intl locale          de_DE
  Timezone             Europe/Berlin (2022-01-18T13:45:22+01:00)
  OPcache              true
  APCu                 false
  Xdebug               false
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit the main Apache config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

look for this section:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Replace *AllowOverride None* with *AllowOverride All*

Activate apache’s rewrite module.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Go to your Symfony project's folder and install Apache pack

```
cd /var/www/html/symfony
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Now:

http://masch3/symfony/public/home -> ok